# Как в Python передать значение переменной из функции одного файла в другой файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, переменные

Интересует вопрос передачи значения переменной из функции в другой файл.
То есть у меня есть файл 1.py и 2.py.
Например в файле 1.py есть функция:

```
def fun():
   d1=0.5
   subprocess.Popen(2.py,shell=True) # Из этой функции запускается второй файл
```

В другом файле например может быть:

```
print(d1)
```

То есть я пробовал через import, но в целом понятно почему не работает...
Как мне передать эту переменную?

Comment: Выглядит как проблема XY? Какова цель всего этого?

Comment: `d1` у вас - локальная переменная функции `fun`. Вы её в том же файле вне функции то достать не сможете, не говоря уже о передаче в другой файл.

Comment: Уж простите, но вам бы почитать основы языка. Сразу отпадут многие тривиальные вопросы.

Comment: Я всё понимаю на счёт основ языка. Просто возникла такая проблема. Вдруг есть какая-то библиотека или ещё что-то что могло мне помочь, поэтому и спросил. Спасибо за ответы.